# C++ Event System - Heap based Event fire

Tags: c++, events, event-handling, game-engine, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've started a journey on my Game Engine and I plan to make it multithreaded. Considering both that and heap allocation costs, I've written an EventPool class that is responsible for caching Event allocations, thus reducing heap allocations, but it adds an additional cost to search for a previously allocated 'free' event pointer of the same type. Ideally, you would want to do only stack allocations, but I'm not sure if that is even possible considering downcasting is required for each EventType.

Is it better to do heap allocation per event fire and delete per frame or keep the EventPool and search from it?

Event fire:

```
template<typename EventType>
static void Publish(const EventType& e)
{
    const auto& handlerIt = m_Subscribers.find(typeid(EventType));

    if (handlerIt == m_Subscribers.end())
    {
        return;
    }

    auto ev = EventPool::Allocate<EventType>(e);

    for (auto& handler : handlerIt->second)
    {
        if (!ev->IsHandled())
        {
            ev->m_Handled = handler(ev);
        }
    }

    ev->m_Handled = true;
}
```

If the EventPool approach is better, how can I optimize it a bit more?

EventPool allocator:

```
template<class EventType>
static EventType* Allocate(const EventType& e)
{
    const auto& poolIt = m_EventPool.find(typeid(EventType));

    EventType* newEvent;
    if (poolIt == m_EventPool.end())
    {
        newEvent = new EventType;
        memcpy(newEvent, &e, sizeof(EventType));
        m_EventPool[typeid(EventType)].push_back(newEvent);
        return newEvent;
    }
    else
    {
        for (Event* ev : poolIt->second)
        {
            if (ev->IsHandled())
            {
                newEvent = static_cast<EventType*>(ev);
                memcpy(newEvent, &e, sizeof(EventType));
                return newEvent;
            }
        }

        newEvent = new EventType;
        memcpy(newEvent, &e, sizeof(EventType));
        poolIt->second.push_back(newEvent);
        return newEvent;
    }
}
```

Comment: That `do heap allocation per event fire and delete per frame` makes me think that none of your events live longer than a game frame (even when unhandled by the end of it). Am I right?

Comment: yes, at least not on single-threaded. in multithreaded system, the event's handle may be delayed

Comment: I've missed this "(even when unhandled by the end of it)". The answer is no, they wont be deleted until they are handled.

Answer (score 0):

According to

> `template<typename EventType> static void Publish(const EventType& e)`

, the compiler knows all the types of your events in advance (because it has to instantiate the `Publish` template function for each of them). You can use this fact to avoid runtime type dispatch completely. For example:

```
template<typename E> using Subscriber = bool (*)(E const&); // or whatever it is

template<typename... Es> // all of the events which may be worked with go here
class EventPool {
private:
  std::tuple<std::vector<Es>...> storages; // a storage per event type
  std::tuple<std::vector<Subscriber<Es>>...> subscribers; // a list of subscribers per event type
  // or whatever you prefer over vectors

public:
  template<typename E> void publish(E const& event) {
    get<E>(storages).push_back(event); // or whatever your (re)allocation policy is
    for (auto& handler: get<Subscriber<E>>(subscribers))
      if (event.handled = handler(event))
        break;
  }
};
```

Now all that RTTI `find(typeid(E))` is gone - instead, you choose the appropriate storage for your event type at compile-time via `std::get` over a tuple of all possible variants. Besides, you need no unsafe downcasts with that

> `newEvent = static_cast<EventType*>(ev)`

because you don't need to restore the type as long as you don't erase it, like in this approach.

Speaking about heap allocations - your events won't need to be `new`ed one by one, which saves you a ton of allocations. Instead, a storage (dynamic array (`std::vector`) in my case) is provided for every event type, so the events can be stored in-place.

Answer (score 0):

### Data structure

It sounds like you would have need for a "pool allocator", which is a special kind of allocator type. We also have "stack allocator", "linear allocator", "double-ended stack allocator", "heap allocator", etc.

This article gives a good overview of the memory operations involved:
http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/compilers/writing-a-pool-allocator/

However, such an allocator **only** works when the type of event, ie. `EventType`, has a predictable and unmodified size in bytes. The implementation of a pool allocator depends on an array, where each element's memory is `reinterpret_cast`'ed to a `EvenType*` to the next free item. It thus uses an implicit free-list but without a separate list structure since the list is contained inside the data. This is very simple code to showcase how that would work:

```
// This static assert is very important!
static_assert(sizeof(EventType) >= sizeof(void*));

EvenType pool[5];
EventType* free_ptr = &pool[0];

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<EventType*>(&pool[i]);
    *ptr = &pool[i+1];
}
auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<EventType*>(&pool[4]);
*ptr = nullptr;

// now allocate
EventType* new_ptr = nullptr;
if (free_ptr == nullptr)
{
    // failed to allocate!
}
new_ptr = free_ptr;
free_ptr = reinterpret_cast<EventType*>(*free_ptr);

// Now, free_ptr should point to &pool[1]
```

This is kind of a blueprint for what would happen. This kind of code is very easy to make mistakes with (I likely made a few even though I have done this a lot), so I *strongly* encourage thorough unit-testing.

### Benefits

It sounds like heap allocations was a concern for you, which should always be limited at runtime, **especially** in time-critical systems such as game engine message processing. With a heap allocator, you allocate one big chunk of memory up front and use that memory throughout program lifetime. So you need to know in advance the maximum number of messages that will ever be in-fly at once, at any given moment in time. If that number is surpassed messaged will be thrown away and an error message should be output to the logger.